# Query in QT doesn't get any data

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt

This is rows in my table.
[image: SQL table]

With this code, I get "in" in console.

```cpp
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("SELECT * FROM user");
qry.exec();
if(qry.size() > 0)
    qInfo() << "in";
else
    qInfo() << "error";
```

But with this code, I get "error".

```cpp
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("SELECT age FROM user");
qry.exec();
if(qry.size() > 0)
    qInfo() << "in";
else
    qInfo() << "error";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```cpp
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("SELECT age FROM \"user\"");
qry.exec();
```

The problem is with the table name. Since `user` is a reserved word, some tools (PgAdmin) automatically add double quotes to the name `"user"` and you have to use double quotes when applying to the table. Unfortunately `user` in Postgres is a function (equivalent to `current_user`) hence the first query returns a row without error.

The best solution is to rename the table and not use reserved words as Postgres identifiers (the name of a table, column, view, function, etc).

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("SELECT age FROM user");
if(qry.exec()) {
    while(qry.next()) {
        qInfo()<<"in";
    }
} else {
    qInfo()<<"error";
}
```

Comment: still writes "error"

Comment: QSqlQuery::prepare() has a return value which you should check and also check the QSqlError afterwards.

Comment: QSqlError wirtes QSqlError("42703", "QPSQL: Unable to prepare statement", "ERROR:  column \"password\" doesn't exist\nLINE 1: PREPARE qpsqlpstmt_1 AS SELECT * FROM user WHERE password = ...\n                                                         ^\n(42703)")

And after .exec "QSqlError("42601", "QPSQL: Unable to create query", "ERROR:  syntax error at or near\nLINE 1: EXECUTE \n                ^\n(42601)")"